# How can I run correctly a css-load in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-loader

I'm learning react and I'm trying to put in my personal project some CSS. I was searching for it and I found several ways to do so:

```
javascript

npm run eject 
// and modifi the path [name]__[local]__[]

import Classes from '.../css/style.css'
//using this method

<link rel="stylesheet" src="./css/styles.css">
// in HTML file 

//adding react glamor
```

Which is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi only import in the component for example

```
import './my-style.css'
```

and in the component jsx call clasname normally

```
<div className="my-class-css">
   ...
</div>
```

Like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './my-style.css'
class MyComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="my-class-css">
                ....
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```